# Show continuity and boundedness for function (and try to simplify it)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Consider the function $f\colon (0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}n(n+1)x-n, & \textrm{if }x\in\left[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right], n\in\mathbb{N}\textrm{ odd}\\-n(n+1)x+n+1, & \textrm{if }x\in\left[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right], n\in\mathbb{N}\textrm{ even}\end{cases}
$$
and show that it is bounded and continuous, but **not** uniformly continuous.

---

The first thing I am dealing with is to understand the definition of $f$. I try to simplify it.

When I am not mistaken, then
$$
f(x)=2x-1,\qquad\frac{1}{2}< x\leq 1
$$

and I am trying to simplifiy $f$ also on $\left( 0 , \frac{1}{2}\right]$. I already found out that
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0.
$$

Maybe it is not necessary to simplify $f$ but in the form it is given, it is hard for me to analyse it.

Comment: Did you get $\varepsilon = 2n+1$ and it is achieved at graph with $k+1$ vertices of degree 3, 1 vertex degree 4 and $k-1$ verteces of degree 5? Where $n=2k+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: fix an odd n. Then on the nth interval, the function is a linear function from 0 to 1 (to see this, substitute the endpoints into the equation of f). Now, n+1 is even, and we similarly see that on the n+1st interval the function is a line segment from 1 to 0. Finally, notice that as n increases, the intervals become narrower and closer to 0.

From this, can you tell what the graph of f looks like?

Comment: Kind of a zig-zag

Comment: Correct. And its period of oscillation  decreases (but with the same amplitude) as x gets closer to 0, which is why we don’t have uniform continuity.

Comment: Formally, in order to show that it is not uniformly continuous, I would choose the two sequences $x_n:=1/n$ with $n$ odd and $y_n:=1/n$ with $n$ even as well as $\varepsilon_0=1/2$, then $\lvert x_n-y_n\rvert\to 0$ but $\lvert f(x_n) - f(y_n)\rvert =1>\varepsilon_0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: thats exactly right

Comment: OK, bounded is also clear as $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq 1$. It remains to show continuity

Comment: Continuity is apparent by the way we construct f: check the left and the right limits at each end point